# How do I load a word in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

I want for a variable to be 'name' for example. If I use read(x) and for that variable to be char it will only load the first letter. So if i type 'name' it would be only the first letter.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?

Comment: The char type can only store one character. Use a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the word you refer to is actually called string, so you can declare a variable and read string  in it:

var

```
    msg:string[10];
```

begin

```
    readln(msg);
    writeln(msg);
```

end.